# Translate VEGA-Lite or VEGA chart specification to Grafana

Tags: grafana, vega-lite

My preferred chart specification language is [VEGA-Lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/) (that can be compiled to VEGA)... But I need to translate later to a fragment into a [complete template of Grafana dashboard specification](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/dashboard/).

**It is possible to do automatic or semi-automatic translation?**  Or maybe there are a good guide, explaining the main "clues for translation".

---

### NOTES

- Translation procedures are not simple, I'm aware... Perhaps a good start point is to test the simplest: [VEGA-Lite bar chart](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/bar.html) to Grafana ones.
- We use some "JSON templating" on the top of VEGA-Lite. We don't have time and resources, but our needs are not so complex... The final "translation solution" must be useful: 
  1. to maintain Grafana dashboards or "Grafana chart  templates"; 
  2. to use VEGA-Lite (JSON and visualization) as "inspiration" for the development of Grafana dashboard-templates.  
  The context is like an [agile methodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development#Method_tailoring) that starts with a lot of VEGA-Lite charts and, for some elected charts, end with Grafana... So, we are resigned/accepting a coarse translation process.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it is possible to write translation/parser.

But:

- I wouldn't expect that someone already made it -> you will need to code it
- Grafana functionality is not the same as VEGA-Lite functionality -> you will have undefined cases
- Grafana dashboard model is not very well documented -> you may need reverse engineering and model can be changed before minor Grafana releases (for example recent Grafana 7.0.0 has schemaVersion 25 -> 25 different dashboard models exists historically = 25 different grammars if you want comprehensive implementation)

Go ahead if you have time and resources. https://grafana.github.io/grafonnet-lib/ can be useful here.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the very good clues! I edited the question's text adding a note to say that we use some "JSON templating" on the top of VEGA-Lite, so your suggestion make sense for our filosofy. If the only option is a coarse translation process, we need more [visual check](https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/wp-content/uploads/GrafanaPanelsRow-1-850x400.png).  Can you add some link for "Grafonnet-lib visualization" tool or visual examples?